# How to transfer unallocated space to C: partition on Windows 10 after booting up a clone?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, clone, disk-cloning

I hope I've come to the right place. Recently, I bought a 1 TB SSD that I switched out with my old 256 GB SSD. I put a bootable clone of the 256 GB drive on the 1 TB drive. However, my C: partition stayed the same. The remaining 700-ish GBs unallocated space is NOT directly to the right of my C: partition, (there is a small partition separating them) so I can't just expand my C: partition into the unallocated space. I'm attempting to use AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard to resize my C: partition but it's not allowing me to select the unallocated space in the resize UI. Here is a screenshot of the window in AOMEI. How can I transfer this unallocated space to my C: partition?

[image]

As I wrote in the title, I am currently using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific software you are using, but generally speaking partitions have to be contiguous. You will have to move or delete the smaller partition between the C drive and the unallocated space, so that there's nothing between the two disk areas that you want to combine. The easiest way to accomplish this would probably be to move (via the "Resize/Move Partition" operation on the left) the small partition to the end of the drive, overwriting some of the unallocated space.